React Native Call Keep: End a Call After Caller Hangs Up
Whenever the user answers the call elsewhere, or the caller hangs up, I need to end the call on the user side. I am currently sending a new voip push from the server with an empty handle whenever that happens, and ending the call on the user side, but getting the following error:
NSInternalInconsistencyException Killing app because it never posted an incoming call to the system after receiving a PushKit VoIP push
But if I end the call after reporting it to callkeep, it shows a new voip notificaiton for a couple seconds before terminating the call, and it also shows the on call history on the phone.
Is Voip push notification the correct approach for this, or is there any other way?
Following is my implementation for the didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload funtion:
if (handle!=nil) {
    [RNVoipPushNotificationManager didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:payload forType:(NSString *)type];
    [RNCallKeep reportNewIncomingCall:uuid
                               handle:handle
                           handleType:@"number"
                             hasVideo: NO
                  localizedCallerName:callerName
                      supportsHolding: YES
                         supportsDTMF: YES
                     supportsGrouping: YES
                   supportsUngrouping: YES
                          fromPushKit: YES
                              payload: payload.dictionaryPayload
                withCompletionHandler: completion];
    
  } else {
    [RNCallKeep endCallWithUUID:uuid reason:4];
  }

